# How to make interactive tweet like "Acura"

Tags: javascript, twitter

How this tweet was made?

https://twitter.com/Acura/status/502174391472386048

This not an ordinary twitter card. I have no idea how to fetch the content with javascript in the tweet.

I'am searching all day , but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

If you wan to use these kind of cards, you have to register at ads.twitter.com.